# Data transfer from carplay app to iPhone app with bluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, carplay

I went through several core bluetooth videos and tutorials. I understood concept quite well.
We are reading vehicle chassis number and some more data from hardware. Which we are transferring to iPhone with cable. Now want to achieve this wirelessly over bluetooth.
Can you please guide me to achieve car play app data transfer to iPhone app via bluetooth?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you want to achieve? because carplay and bluetooth doesn't work together. When Carplay is active, bluetooth gets switched off automatically.

Comment: I want to get data from carplay app to iPhone without using cable

Comment: You can use carplay over Wi-Fi  with new systems

Comment: If you have some hardware that is getting the car's hardware data like some auto link that it is limited to that device functionality if it can support communication over bluetooth or Wi-Fi.

Comment: we are reading vehicle chassis number and some more data from hardware.  Which we are transferring to iPhone with cable. Now want to achieve this wirelessly

Comment: I think it is limited to that hardware. If this hardware can support communication over   bluetooth then it could be possible. I am not very sure about it though.

Comment: ok. Its car play hardware. We need to deploy it over a car